# Sencha Touch - Add Markers to Map after Maprender

Tags: google-maps, sencha-touch, google-maps-markers

I want to load markers to my map, in sencha touch, after I load some json data from ajax request. The thing is I don't know how to achieve this after the maprender event is fired.
I've got this:

my map view:

```
app.views.MapTab = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    iconCls: 'map',
    id: 'map',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'map',
        id: 'mapa',
        mapOptions : {
            center : new google.maps.LatLng(50.077721, 14.448585),
            zoom : 12,
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
            }
        },
        listeners : {
            'maprender' : function(comp, map){
                Ext.dispatch({
                    controller: app.controllers.map,
                    action: 'map_rendered',
                    map: map
                });
            }
        }
    }],
    initComponent: function() {
        app.views.MapTab.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

store to load json:

```
app.stores.results = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: "app.models.Results",
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://app.cz/json_list2.php?a=l&zp=1&u=vinohrady-praha&c0=500000&c1=6000000&p0=10&p1=120&cm20=1000&cm21=120000&pg=0&s=Datumu&t=byt&age=30&pod=0&lat=50.075401&lng=14.458344&pp=prodej&tp0=0&tp1=12',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'markers'
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        'load': function (t, r, s) {
            Ext.dispatch({
                controller: app.controllers.map,
                action: 'loaded',
                records: r
            });
        }
    }
});
```

controller

```
app.controllers.map = new Ext.Controller({

    loaded: function(options) {
        for(var i = 0; i < options.records.length; i++){
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: new google.maps.LatLng(options.records[i].get('lat'), options.records[i].get('lng')),
                 map: app.views.mapTab.getComponent('mapa')
            });
        }
        // need to rerender/refresh the map here
    },

    map_rendered: function(options) {
        console.log("map rendered");
    }

});
```

Comment: thanks! your question helped me a ot ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code should work but you are attaching the markers to the Sencha Touch Map component rather than the underlying Google Maps map, which can be accessed with the 'map' property.

```
...
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(options.records[i].get('lat'), options.records[i].get('lng')),
    **map: app.views.mapTab.getComponent('mapa').map**
});
...
```

The map shouldn't need manually re-rendered and should just add them in when you bind them with the map config.